# PhpStorm Doesn't Recognize Doctrine Entity Classes

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

PhpStorm doesn't seem to recognize any of my Doctrine entity classes or their methods.

```
$comment = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Comment')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));

$comment->getId(); 
/* PHPSTORM THROWS WARNING: Method getId() not found in subject class */
```

The error goes away, only when I explicitly comment it - which really clutters my controller.

```
/* @var \MyBundle\Entity\Comment $comment */
$comment = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Comment')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
```

Is there a way to document this for PhpStorm in my Entity Class?

I'm using the Symfony2 plugin with PhpStorm 8.  Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/pbyrne84/DynamicReturnTypePlugin looked promising, but I think it only works on static methods and I don't think it could correctly parse the `MyBundle:` namespace alias.

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue. Magically solved by clearing the Doctrine metadata:

```
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

EDIT: In GitHub reposiory of the symfony plugin there is a brief description on what to do when this issue happens:

https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin

> **Autocomplete (or something else) is not working! Help!**
>
> [...]
>
> Many features require the
>   **app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml** file to exist. It is
>   generated when you boot your app in dev environment (open /app_dev.php
>   in a browser or php app/console).

Since my server is remote, manually synchronizing the file `app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml` solved my problem.

When I was working on a local server, instead, the command I wrote above helped me to make autocomplete work again.

Comment: +1, worked for me. Precisely, for Symfony 3: 
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem with the Symfony2 Plugin, this is maybe not a nice solution but it works

```
/** @var EntityManager $em */
$em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is better than doing comments on each Entity.

Answer (score 2):

your issue should be fixed, now. there was a problem on multiple `getRepository` implementations of proxy classes in cache folder. just update to >= 0.11.81

Answer (score 1):

Now, I prefer declaring repositories as services so you don't have those typehint problems:

```
services:
    MyBundle\Entity\CommentRepository:
        class: MyBundle\Entity\CommentRepository
        public: true
        factory: ['@doctrine', getRepository]
        arguments:
            - MyBundle\Entity\Comment
```

Then in your controller :

```
use MyBundle\Entity\CommentRepository;

$comment = $this->get(CommentRepository::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate caches of PhpStorm. Go to file->Invalidate caches